# set magento catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all cron at 2.30

Tags: magento

researched to set the cron job @2.30 and unable to find the solution. please see the issue below from Magento_Root_Directory.

./app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0 2 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>catalog/observer::reindexProductPrices</model>
            </run>
        </catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

see above code. I want to set the cron @2.30 AM

Can i please know the syntax to set up the cron job?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html
after instal it you need to navigate to : **System**>>**Scheduler**>>**Scheduler** **Configuration** then clic on **Cron Configuration** button.
you can here edit your cron.